# How can I add a MapActivity in an ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ViewGroup dividing a screen in two layouts, each one has a different Activity: one a map and the other one a list. This ViewGroup is inside a Tab Layout.

The problem is that in this conditions, the map does not finish loading or updating and the list works really slow.

Does anyone know hoy I can get this layout in a different way or how to solve the problem with the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them both in the same Activity, in this case a `MapActivity`, where your layout consists of a `ListView` and `MapView` side-by-side.  From the information given, I can't see why each subcomponent needs to be a full-blown Activity.

HTH

Comment: I was using a ListActivity, so I did not thought about using ListView. Thank you very much. It works perfectly.